# RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation

Tags: python, pytorch, runtime-error

I am getting this error on a code implemented in Pytorch 0.3. I am trying to run the code but I am getting this error.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:4044: UserWarning: Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed to align_corners=False since 1.3.0. Please specify align_corners=True if the old behavior is desired. See the documentation of grid_sample for details.
"Default grid_sample and affine_grid behavior has changed "
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py:718: UserWarning: Named tensors and all their associated APIs are an experimental feature and subject to change. Please do not use them for anything important until they are released as stable. (Triggered internally at /pytorch/c10/core/TensorImpl.h:1156.)
return torch.max_pool2d(input, kernel_size, stride, padding, dilation, ceil_mode)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "eval_pf_pascal.py", line 73, in
corr4d = model(batch)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/ncnet/lib/model.py", line 275, in forward
corr4d = self.NeighConsensus(corr4d)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/ncnet/lib/model.py", line 147, in forward
x = self.conv(x)+self.conv(x.permute(0,1,4,5,2,3)).permute(0,1,4,5,2,3)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/container.py", line 139, in forward
input = module(input)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
File "/content/ncnet/lib/conv4d.py", line 126, in forward
use_half=self.use_half,
File "/content/ncnet/lib/conv4d.py", line 52, in conv4d
padding=padding,
RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this.

Comment: I think it would be a good time for you to post some code, do you think we can just guess what the error is?

Comment: "Pytorch 0.3" OMG :( we are in 1.9... let us know which pytorch version you're using as well... you said the version it was implemented

Comment: @Berriel 1.9 do you know how to install 0.3 in colab

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing an operation such as
tensor1 += tensor2

Try
tensor1.data += tensor2